# How to filtering list with count sub array's field?

Tags: mongodb

This is example one of document in MongoDB.

```json
{
    "content" : "I just said that before. I'll never be with you.",
    "analysis" : [
        {
            "sentence" : "I just said that before.",
            "sentiment" : "neutral",
            "subject" : "I",
            "expression" : "say"
        },
        {
            "sentence" : "I'll never be with you.",
            "sentiment" : "negative",
            "subject" : "I",
            "expression" : "be",
            "label": "Farewell"
        }
    ]
}
```

There every analysis element can has "label" or no.

I want to filter this document for put "label" in analysis element.

I need document list that `analysis.label.count < analysis.count`

I tried this query
`{ $and: [{ "analysis": { $exists: true } }, { "analysis.label": { $exists: false } }] }`.

But it returns only has no label in any analysis' element.

Do I need aggregate()? or find() with query?

Comment: simply check condition `.find({ "analysis.label": null })`.

Comment: @turivishal chaged query `{ $and: [{ "analysis": { $exists: true } }, { "analysis.label": null }] }` It work! I don't know how 'null' works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires `$elemMatch` operator to match `$exists` false condition in array,

```
{
  analysis: {
    $exists: true,
    $elemMatch: {
      label: {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A0VvNy6PTxo)

---

The second approach checking `null` condition,

```
{
  analysis: {
    $exists: true
  },
  "analysis.label": null
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NHe63wmNVd3)

Comment: Oh, It work. Is there difference with your condition and this `{ $and: [{ "analysis": { $exists: true } }, { "analysis.label": null }] }`? Both query returns same result.

Comment: the `$exists` will check if the property exists in the document, and the `null` will check both the conditions, if the field exists or if it exists then null? so both will work in your situation.